# list index out of range

Tags: python, list

I can't figure out why this is throwing up a "List index out of range error". This code is meant to remove duplicates from a list.

```
def remove_duplicates(l):
   new_list = l 
   for i in range(0,len(l)):
      store = l[i]
      for x in range(i+1,len(l)):
         if l[x] == store:
            new_list.pop(x)
   return new_list 
print remove_duplicates([1,1,2,2])
```

Thanks for all the answers. So i tried this (after considerable brain-wracking ) and i can't figure out what's wrong this time.

```
def remove_duplicates(l):
   new_list = l[:]
   for i in range(0,len(l)):
       count = 0
       store = l[i]
       for x in range(0,len(new_list)):
          if l[x] == store:
             count += 1 

      if count >= 2:
         new_list.remove(l[i])

return new_list
print remove_duplicates([1,1,2,2])
```

Which print [2,2] to the console. I used the remove function, so it can't be an indexing error. I don't see how it can remove the 1 on the second iteration. I'm looping over the modified list in the second for loop, there's no way the count can be >= 2 in the if condition.

Comment: Ok thanks. I get the problem. Just when you think you've written a nifty little piece of code huh? I like that people on this forum just don't give it away :)

Comment: So i can't go about this with a nested for loop ?

Comment: You can do it with nested for loops. You got into trouble because pop changes the part of the list you haven't processed yet. The trick is to run through the list backwards.

Comment: Point of clarification, you have a variable called `new_list` but its really just another reference to the original list. Is the intention to create a new list or change the existing list in place?

Answer (score 2):

`new_list = l` makes `new_list` refer to the same object as `l`. Any changes to `new_list` will then affect `l`, which causes errors in your code. You get the out-of-range error because you remove items from `new_list`, which actually removes them from `l`, while you're iterating over `l`.

Use `new_list = l[:]` to copy `l` to a new list.

You also have errors with the logic of your code: `new_list.pop(x)` will change the indexes of all the following elements, which means the next time you remove an element, it will be removed from the wrong index.

Answer (score 0):

You are not copying the list properly, your **new_list** refers to the same memory location i.e. object as **l** hence any change you make in new_list will reflect in l as well.
To avoid this you can use shallow copy 
example:-

```
new_list=l[:]
```

Answer (score 0):

List comprehensions tend to be much faster than for loops and look fancy to boot. if your intention is to create a new list with duplicates removed, this will do it:

```
def remove_duplicates(mylist):
    return [elem for i, elem in enumerate(mylist) if elem not in mylist[i+1:]]

print remove_duplicates([1,1,2,2])
```

If you have a very large list with many duplicates, a for loop with a set() to track what you've seen may be faster.